# Office Add-In certification fails due to missing privacy policy link

Tags: office-store

In 2019 I have published an Word Add-In in the Office store. Last week-end I have updated the application, changing the UI and expanding its functionality. In the same time I have hosted it on a new domain. I have also updated the privacy policy as I am using a Google Analytics tag for obtaining data regarding the use of the application.

Considering the change in the URL I have submitted with the Office store a new manifest file for approval.

Following the certification process i have received a message mentioning that the validation has failed due to a critical validation failure related to *100.6.1  Privacy Policy*

Below is the message body:

> Privacy Policy links must lead to information on your policies
> regarding users’ personal information (*a link to the old
> privacy policy from the old domain is inserted here*) Please update the Privacy Policy
> link in the offer listing and re-submit your offer. Please Note: The
> privacy policy must be displayed on the page opened.

The office add-in is developed as an SPA based on Vue framework. The Privacy Policy link is placed in the footer of the website and is not an actual html link but a button which on a click event will display an overlay and a modal containing the privacy policy text.
In the offer listing (which in my mind refers to the Dashboard of the add-in in the Partner Center) the url for the privacy policy is the main url of the add-in as the button displaying he privacy modal appears on all pages (routes) of the application.

I am not quite sure if the problem arise from the fact that privacy policy is not an actual html link leading to a new web page or there are other issues regarding the content of the policy itself.
In the Microsoft Partner Center Dashboard, in the Properties Section of the Add-In i have an alert stating the following:

> To pass certification, your privacy policy must include:
>
> - Information on your policies regarding user's personal information
> - Refer to the app or your service overall and NOT your website
> - Your service description must include the name of app submitted
> - A valid URL link that does not generate a 404 error

Again, I am not sure if this is an alert message customized to my particular situation or is just a general alert which wish to emphasize some general requirements regarding the privacy policy.
The commercial marketplace certification policies that you can find at this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#1006-personal-information
are not very informative in this respect.

So my questions are:

It is mandatory for passing the certification process to actually have the privacy policy as an html link that opens in a separate page or it can be a modal?

Why the e-mail mentioning the failure is referring to the old privacy policy (which was indeed an html link leading to a new web page)? Is this is an indication that I need to keep the old way of displaying this privacy policy?

Considering that this is a Single Page Application a separate route for privacy policy will pass the certification process?

**Any help on this matter will be appreciated, as i am not certain of what I need to change**.

It will not hurt that this validation failure message to be more specific, either.

Comment: Customer service questions are off topic here - For assistance on Microsoft Commercial Marketplace, Azure Marketplace, AppSource and Certification issues, please sign-in to Marketplace Publisher Support at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
 
 · Create a ticket in Partner Center
 · Browse Topics
 · Category: Commercial Marketplace
 · Topic: Certification
 · Sub-Topic: Office Add-in
 · Next step: Review solutions
provide issue details

Comment: "Need more help? Visit the Office Developer Center and explore the documentation, blog posts, and other support resources that are available. You can also ask technical questions to the wider developer community or connect with the validation team on Stack Overflow" - This is was inserted in the e-mail received from Microsoft Partner Center highlighting the validation failure. That it is why I have posted here!

Comment: This is another recommendation in the MPC -  "For general questions about policies, processes, or validation requirements, engage with the review team via Stack Overflow . Tag your question with "Office-Store". Please be aware that the review team will not be able to discuss individual submission results on Stack Overflow."

Comment: I have created the ticket! Thanks for the support!